# What is the best way to display empty fields in a user card?

Tags: forms, input-fields, cards, empty

I'm creating a user widget for dashboard. What is the best way to fill the empty fields here?

[image]

I can't hide the labels here if they are empty. And if I use "No information available" does it seems overkill? Can anyone help me with any guidance!

Comment: So it's not really empty space you are referring to, but fields that don't have any content in them yet. Is that correct?

Comment: @JonW, Yes you are correct I'm referring to the fields that don't have any content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't leave fields blank

When a field is blank, the user has no indication that the blank space is intentional (and not a page/widget error).  It's for the same reason that publishers print [*intentionally blank*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionally_blank_page) notices in books to avoid user confusion:

[image: blank]

The presentation in your screenshot (using the `-` indicator) works fine from a usability perspective.

---

### A more modern approach

Users nowadays have an unpredictable number of devices and email/phone/physical addresses.  So a popular contemporary approach to user cards (used by Google Contacts, Android/iOS and other apps) is:

[image]

This approach provides flexibility with the number of fields in a card, and hides blanks fields to simplify the presentation.

It's up to you to decide whether this pattern is suitable for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for the user to edit these details?

If they're not locked down then it might be worth encouraging the user to populate these empty items by adding some sort of edit state trigger titled something like 'Add details'.

It would seem a shame to waste the opportunity of displayed empty fields to remind users to populate them.

Comment: This user card details is only for managers and the user registration is happened when they submit a feedback for from outlets. Here curd will not be happened.